# Running python from a conda environment on windows

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have decided to have both python 2 and 3 installed on my Windows PC. Python 3 was included with Anaconda, and works flawlessly after the installation of Anaconda.

After having created successfully a python 2 environment:

```
conda create --name py27 python=2.7
```

I noticed that no python.py file has been created in *C:\Users\Hélain\IT\Anaconda3\envs\py27*.

Typing *python* in my terminal launches my python 3 python and *py27* is not considered a command. Activating or deactivating the environment does no change this behavior.

Result of typing *python*:

```
C:\Users\Hélain>activate py27
Deactivating environment "C:\Users\Hélain\IT\Anaconda3"...
Activating environment "C:\Users\Hélain\IT\Anaconda3\envs\py27"...

[py27] C:\Users\Hélain>python
Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:32:42) [MSC v.1
600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

How do I run python with my environment's version and packages?

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal type:

```
activate py27
```

The prompt should change to `(py27)`.

Now you can install packages in this environment. For example:

```
conda install jupyter matplotlib
```

Launch Python from this terminal with:

```
python
```

Comment: The prompt did indeed change... But the python version is still Python 3.4:
C:\Users\Hélain>activate py27
Deactivating environment "C:\Users\Hélain\IT\Anaconda3"...
Activating environment "C:\Users\Hélain\IT\Anaconda3\envs\py27"...

[py27] C:\Users\Hélain>python
Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:32:42) [MSC v.1
600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: Try: `C:\Users\Hélain\IT\Anaconda3\envs\py27\bin\python`.

Comment: There is no "bin" folder in py27... Is it normal?

Comment: Did you set up virtual environments for both python2 and python3?

Comment: This is the cleanest option. Create a Python 3 environment: `conda create --name py36 python=3.6` and switch between them. If Python 3 is the default, i.e. the root environment, you can also use this instead. But having two envs is often the better option.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to run python code written in python 2.7 syntax.

In order to run any python file (for example, as you mention python.py) after successfully [creating a conda environment](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html) is-

1. Activate the environment - `activate py27`
    This works on windows. In [linux/mac](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html) type `source activate py27`
   Prompt should change to `(py27)`.
2. Navigate to the directory where you *created* your `python.py` file.
    If you have not created any `.py` file, simply open a notepad and rename it as `python.py`. Write your code. Right now for testing purpose, simply write `print "Hello"`.
3. Now in the terminal just enter `python.py` or the name of python file. It should run and print Hello.

I am not that experienced to know much about the python version conflict you encountered while running the python command. But you should check the github repo for [issues related to conda](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues) for more information on this. It may be a bug.

Comment: "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("hello")?"; it is still using python 3!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `python.exe` in your environment? From my understanding, all your Pycharm projects can point to the same Anaconda interpreter (stored outside the environment folders) and then to propagate an envrionment change to Pycharm, you just need to do it from the Conda prompt